# How to substitute section of character values (i.e., string) within a large data frame in R?

Tags: r

I am cleaning and processing text data about school districts. The data frame is organized as follows:

| County | District | ID | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01 | "Text for District 1 " |
| 1 | 2 | 02 | "Text for District 2" |
| 1 | 3 | 03 | "so on" |
| 1 | 4 | 04 | "and " |
| 2 | 5 | 05 | "so" |
| 2 | 6 | 06 | "forth" |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 58 | 850 | 0850 | "Text for District 58" |

The values of text are of concern here and are long sections of text in character form. Contained in *some* values of the text variable are string sections such as the following: "Funds are being spent.We know". The absence of a space following the period is my purpose for posting. I would like to substitute all instances of a period with a space such that the previous string is converted to "Funds are being spent We know". I have tried the following to substitute the period for an empty space (" "):

`Dataframe <- Dataframe %>% str_replace_all(Text, ".", " ")`

`if (str_detect(Dataframe$Text, ".") {Dataframe$Text <- str_replace_all(Text, ".", " ")}`

`Dataframe <- Dataframe %>% gsub(".", " ", Text)`

All my attempts have left me unsuccessful and frustrated.

Some other issues I have encountered which I will address in other posts (why not mention it here in case someone knows a resolution) are instances in which the Text variable has values which contain a section of text which has been erroneously concatenated such as the following: "Wearefocusedonsolving". I am looking for a way to insert a space in between each word - "We are focused on solving". Another issue is spelling mistakes (not from processing but mistakes in the text data itself) and I am looking for a way to resolve them - e.g., "focuseb" instead of "focused".

Comment: Try `Dataframe$Text <- gsub('.', ' ', Dataframe$Text, fixed = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the period as period is a special character.
In `R` we use `\\` to escape a special character:

```
text <- "Funds are being spent.We know"

library(stringr)
str_replace_all(text, "\\.", " ")

"Funds are being spent We know"
```